# how to access java class in android activity from putting it in a package?

Tags: java, android, function, class, model

I m calling it in method by creating function with the java class from another package..

```
 private void drawRegressionLine() {

    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Regression line view ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayList<String> point = new ArrayList<String>();

    Algorithm algorithm = new MaxLikelihood() {

    point = c.KNN(point);
    plot(point);
    };`
```

Comment: Could you please paste your Activity code and describe your problem more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

```
package firstpackagename;
import secondpackagename.*; /*add other necessary imports*/
public class MainActivity extends Activity {@
    Override public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
        super.onCreate(s);
        TheClassInOtherPackage X = new TheClassInOtherPackage(); /*If empty constructor used*/
        Object o = X.methodInOtherpackage(params1, params2, ....); /*Replace this with X.methodInOtherpackage(...) if method returns voids. Replace object o with the proper return type*/
    }
}
```

Note - You can also return values from the constructor by adding a return type to it just like the methods. Hope this helps. :)